# Help With Sending a Mail in PHP Using Mail Function

Tags: php, email

My code-

```
$from = "From:Company\n\r";
$mesg = include('mail.html');
function mail($u,'hey',$mesg);
```

basically, i want to send the mail, where the message needs to be the mail.html.

help...the mesage needs to be sent to `$u`.

Comment: also I need the mail to be cc to support@example.com. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you redefining the mail question? * On a sidenote, I'd suggest using [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead of the simple php `mail` function.

Comment: you didn't even bother searching for PHP mail on SO right? All 'related' topics show up on the right with sufficient answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example (composed from the examples in the manual) of how you can do this when using [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/):

```
<?php

require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

//Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

  //Give the message a subject
  ->setSubject('Your subject')

  //Set the From address with an associative array
  ->setFrom(array('your@email.com' => 'Your Name'))

  //Set the To addresses with an associative array
  ->setTo(array('recipient@domain.org' => 'Recipient\'s name'))

  //Set CC
  ->setCc('support@example.com')

  //Give it a body
  ->setBody(file_get_contents('mail.html'))

  ;

//Create the Mailer
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance(Swift_MailTransport::newInstance());

//Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: @Czechnology That is so cool. Thanks... Can u also tell me how to use $u instead of the recipient email. $u is the username while registering. Thanks

Comment: @Czechnology Also, Do I need to only include one file from so mnay files in the library?

Comment: @sarthak, you can't send email to an username, you need an email address. If you have user's email address _and_ his name, you can use `->setTo(array('users@emailaddress.com' => 'Username'))`.

Comment: @sarthak, you only need to include one file which takes care of including the other files (if require). But of course, you need all the files saved in your system.

Comment: @Czechnology well, the email is stored in $_POST['email'] or $email...how do i use that?

Comment: You can also specify different types of the transport, see [Swift Mailer: Transport Types](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/transport-types) if you need to. Swift Mailer has a lot of options, you should take a few minutes to fly through the manual - you'll realize how powerful it is!

Comment: @sarthak, `->setTo($_POST['email'])` or `->setTo($email)` if you don't want to use user's name. Or `->setTo(array($email => $username))` if you want to include user's name. Please check your POST input before using it (e.g. check if the email address is valid etc).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `function` in front of mail, just do

```
mail($emailto, $subject, file_get_contents('mail.html'), $headers);
```

Comment: check out php's doc page for mail http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - has many examples of how to construct a mail message.  `$headers` is also for CC

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because `include()` includes a file and evaluates (interprets the contents), you are trying to make it act like a function that returns a value which it is not.

What you need to do is read the contents of the file into a variable using `file_get_contents()` or a simillar function and then use it as the message body.

Comment: should I use the normal php mail function or a better one like swiftmail etc?

Comment: Read through the whole page, and the php manual page for mail. It's really easy once you take a moment to understand how it works. As far as your second question, that really depends. If you are trying to send mass mail, or need advanced features such as mime attachments and such, you should look into SwiftMailer, PHPMailer or similar solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use the PHPMailer Class really it will give you a lot of facilites and features and also the download contains examples you will need to include the class file then use it its free. for mor information [go to this link](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)